# How to make text boxes appear using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint

I am trying to make the corresponding textarea appear when `Abnormal` is clicked and disappear when `Normal` is clicked. The problem I am having is that when I click `Abnormal` for one question it affects both textareas and not the one it corresponds to.

```js
$("[nfield='horizontal_field']").on("change", function() {
  $("[mrbvalue='Normal']").on('change', function() {
    if ($("[mrbvalue='Normal']:checked")) {
      $('[nfield="txt_fieldhori"]').show()
    }
  });

  $("[mrbvalue='Abnormal']").on('change', function() {
    if ($("[mrbvalue='Abnormal']:checked")) {
      $('[nfield="txt_fieldhori"]').hide()
    }
  });
})

$("[nfield='vert_field']").on('change', function() {
  $("[mrbvalue='Normal']").on('change', function() {
    if ($("[mrbvalue='Normal']:checked")) {
      $('[nfield="txt_nooo"]').show()
    }
  });
  
  $("[mrbvalue='Abnormal']").on('change', function() {
    if ($("[mrbvalue='Abnormal']:checked")) {
      $('[nfield="txt_nooo"]').hide()
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="n-mrb n-choice q" nfield="horizontal_field">
  <div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="horizontal_field" mrbvalue="Normal" class="k-valid"> Normal</label></div>
  <div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="horizontal_field" mrbvalue="Abnormal" class="k-valid"> Abnormal</label></div>
</div>
<textarea class="n-text comment -EntireLine ee k-valid" nfield="txt_fieldhori" id="tet"></textarea>
<div class="n-mrb n-choice q" nfield="vert_field">
  <div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="vert_field" mrbvalue="Normal" class="k-valid"> Normal</label></div>
  <div class="mrb-item"><label><input type="radio" name="vert_field" mrbvalue="Abnormal" class="k-valid"> Abnormal</label></div>
</div>
<textarea class="n-text comment -EntireLine ee k-valid" nfield="txt_nooo" id="te"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all `textarea` instances when an event occurs on the radio, and you're also unnecessarily nesting the event handlers.

To fix this you can simply hook a single event handler to all radio buttons which toggles the visibility of the related `textarea`, which can be retrieved using jQuery's DOM traversal methods, based on the selected value.

Also note that your HTML has a lot of invalid non-standard attributes. These either need to be removed or converted to data attributes, for example: `data-nfield="txt_fieldhori"`. In either case you need to ensure you put a `value` attribute on the radio input elements themselves.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(":radio").on("change", function() {
  $(this).closest('.n-choice').next('textarea').toggle(this.value === 'Normal');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="n-mrb n-choice q">
  <div class="mrb-item">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="horizontal_field" value="Normal" class="k-valid" checked="true"> 
      Normal
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="mrb-item">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="horizontal_field" value="Abnormal" class="k-valid"> 
      Abnormal
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<textarea class="n-text comment -EntireLine ee k-valid" id="tet"></textarea>
<div class="n-mrb n-choice q">
  <div class="mrb-item">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="vert_field" value="Normal" class="k-valid" checked="true"> 
      Normal
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="mrb-item">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="vert_field" value="Abnormal" class="k-valid"> 
      Abnormal
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<textarea class="n-text comment -EntireLine ee k-valid"  id="te"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but I can't add value attr or checked attr because sharepoint generates it.

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating it and selecting all corresponding items instead the one you are interested about. Let's have a simpler, correct solution along with explanation:

```
var textAreas = document.querySelectorAll("textarea.n-text.comment");
var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
for (let index = 0; index < radioButtons.length; index++) {
    radioButtons[index].addEventListener("change", function() {
      textAreas[(index - (index % 2)) / 2].style.display = (index % 2) ? "none" : "block";
  });
}
```

What happens:

- we load all text areas into an array-like object
- we load all radio buttons into an array-like object
- we loop through the set of radio buttons, using the `let` keyword to acquire block context for the `index`
- we add a change event for the current radio button
- `(index - (index % 2)) / 2` yields the correct text area `index` from the radio button `index`
- each pair radio button should hide the text area and each odd should show
- we change the `display` accordingly

Comment: Thanks I realize I am over complicating it and this is dirty code, but I do it the best I can then I make it better later. I tried out your code and added your script but I keep getting an error on ".style".

Comment: @Pvas have you tried out the JSFiddle? In my previous comment here I have shared a link to JSFiddle where this works, proving that the code in my answer solves the issue.